# How to filter list in react admin

Tags: react-admin

For some reason in react admin I am having trouble filtering the list on the table. Here's my code

```
/* eslint-disable */
import * as React from "react";
import { List, Datagrid, TextField, TextInput, ReferenceInput, SelectInput } from 'react-admin';
import GetEntityNames from "./GetEntityName";

const postFilters = [
    <TextInput source="audience_name" label="Search Audience Label" />,
];


const AudienceLabelList = props => (
    <List filters={postFilters} {...props}>
        <Datagrid rowClick="edit">
            <TextField source="id" />
            <TextField source="audience_name" label="Audience Labels" />
            <TextField source="entity_ids" label="Entity_ids" />
            <GetEntityNames source="entity_ids" />
        </Datagrid>
    </List>
);

export default AudienceLabelList;
```

When I type in an entry on my list, in order for me to see results it has to be an exact match. For example when I search

```
tags
```

I want it to return

```
tags are many
```

That's not happening I have to search based on exact match for some reason

Answer (score 1):

In react-admin, filtering is performed only on the server, react-admin only adds filter parameters to the request.

Comment: So does that mean I won't have any control over the way my data is being filtered?

Comment: If your server implements the filtering you need, you only need to generate the right request.
If react-admin generates a request different from what is needed for your server, you can implement your dataProvider.